# Making Raster of Northings (for use in Maxent) in ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, arcgis-10.2, spatial-analyst, maxent

I'm working on building Maxent species distribution models for rockfish along the Northern California Coast. To do this I need rasters of predictor variables, and I want to capture latitudinal variation in habitat.

Basically I want to duplicate the Northing coordinate of the raster into the cell value. Seems simple, but it's been driving me nuts.

I'm running ArcMap 10.2 with the spatial analyst package.

Comment: Have a look at 1st line in my answer http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/217756/how-to-add-and-calculate-x-and-y-attributes-in-an-integer-raster/217776#217776

Answer (score 1):

I created a polyline feature along southern extent of my raster layer, and then used the Euclidean Distance tool to create a raster of distances from that polyline. I'm going to use "distance from southern extent" as a Maxent predictor instead of the Northing.